# Scaling of Tikz-drawn figures and hidden paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I want a certain path that I generate to remain hidden (so I use the path command without actually drawing it), so that I can use that path to compute other points of interest such as intersections, but I don't want that hidden path to affect the overall scaling of my shown figure. Is there a way to generate such a path that does not affect the overall figure scaling?

Comment: Is `\path[overlay] ...` what you are looking for? If not, please add a short test document to your question so we can see what problems you face.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it is, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!